# How to add the functionality of range slider into normal slider

Tags: ios, uislider

As title, how can I implement a 2 way slider as below link? Should I overlay a subview upon normal slider to simulate UI when trim video?

http://www.imore.com/record-trim-videos-ipad

Comment: not sure if I got this right...but cant you have a slider let's say from 0 to 10 and whatever value is selected just subtract 5 and get the [-5 , 5] range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I used 3 `UIImageView` to represent "thumb", "bounding frame", "background thumbnail" to simulate it. These 3 images are added to my custom slider from top to bottom as subviews. To switch if we are in playback or trim video mode, we only need to handle touch by region.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for "range slider iOS" there are a few out there, though none I've found were complete enough for me. Maybe one will fit your needs.

Here's one [ios-range-slider](http://buildmobile.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/) and another: [double-slider](http://dev.doukasd.com/2010/08/double-slider/)